# Can't make emacs compile with locally installed harfbuzz

Tags: compile

Whenever I start the ./configure script for emacs at the end of it I get the following message:

```
configure: WARNING: This configuration uses the Cairo graphics library,
    but not the HarfBuzz font shaping library (minimum version 0.9.42).
    We recommend the use of HarfBuzz when using Cairo, please install
    appropriate HarfBuzz development packages.
```

I compiled and installed harfbuzz 2.7.2 in my ~/opt/harfbuzz-2.7.2 directory. In my .profile I put:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/myuser/opt/harfbuzz-2.7.2/include/ $CPPFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/myuser/opt/harfbuzz-2.7.2/lib/ $LDFLAGS"
```

But emacs configure doesn't pick it up. I guess it only finds my system harfbuzz-dev (debian 8, not recent enough).

What do I need to do to make configure understand where harfbuzz is? Do I need to recompile Cairo?

Comment: Emacs' configure uses `pkg-config` to search for HarfBuzz, so you need to ensure that your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` points at the pkconfig directory for your new installation of HarfBuzz

Comment: @rpluim Thanks that was it. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs' configure uses `pkg-config` to search for HarfBuzz, so you need to ensure that your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` points at the pkconfig directory for your new installation of HarfBuzz (this is true for a lot of other packages that Emacs tries to use)